# modify .htaccess to allow ajax access to one file

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a website www.myurl.com

It has the following layout

```
/home/html/.htaccess
/home/html/application
/home/html/application/.htaccess
/home/html/application/controllers/stats.php
```

/home/html/.htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

/home/html/application/.htaccess contains:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

I don't know if this is significant, but the site is powered by CodeIgniter.

Here's my problem, I am making the following Ajax call:

```
                   $.ajax({
                   url: '<?php echo site_url('stats/get_stuff')?>',
                   type:'POST',
                   data: { parm1 : "parm1", 
                           parm2 : "parm2",
                           parm3 : "parm3" }, 
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(output_string){
                   }

<?php echo site_url('stats/get_stuff')?> returns: 


http://www.myurl.com/stats/get_stuff
```

and the Ajax call gives the following error:

http://www.myurl.com/stats/get_stuff   401 Unauthorized

I'm pretty certain i have to modify one or both of the .htaccess files but I'm unsure which one and, most importantly what I have to change.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Before change .htaccess, try to set a `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'`; on your `config.php` file.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081684/ajax-call-needs-username-and-password for answer